# Php - Search Box, pagination disappear when data from MySQL has shown

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I have no clue anymore how I can solve this problem, components of Datatables have dissapeared : Searchbox, Pagination, number of length.

i thought it was caused by myself in the  PHP code, but this is not the case.

there are many errors that are showing, `id=example, error JSON response` Second one `AJAX error`.

and now I found this, that is why I am asking my question now.

The code below shows just `name` but other components of the table are gone.

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="datatable" class="display" width="100%">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                require_once("Connection.php");
                $connection = new Connection();
                $conn = $connection->getConnection();
                try{
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM identitas";
                    $getData = $conn->prepare($sql);
                    $getData->execute();
                    $result = $getData->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    foreach($result as $data){
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $data['nama']?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                }catch(PDOException $e){
                    echo "ERROR : " . $e->getMessage();
                }
                ?>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

how to call `Datatables`

```
 <!-- for data table-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.11/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables-1.10.11/media/js/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables-1.10.11/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


        <!-- javascript-->
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#datatable').dataTable({
                    "dom": '<"top"fl>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">'
                });
            });
      </script>
```